# Any tool or browser add on to check POST/ GET response?

Tags: php, post

Suppose I have test.php file which echo the value of *user* and *data* .Now  I can easily check my test.php whether it is working fine or not from a HTML form with *user* and *data*
input. But I want to check my test.php file without html form.

Is there any tool or browser plugin to POST or to GET data from test.php.

```
//test.php.
<?php

   echo $_POST['user'];
   echo $_POST['data'];

?>
```

Thanks in advance

**Update** I have found RESTclient and its really fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to simply watch webpages interact with your service using Fiddler; you'll then understand what format the service expects.

To send requests in Fiddler, click the **Composer** tab and fill in the headers and body.

Answer (score 0):

Its fairly straightforward to execute a POST request from the CLI using cURL

```
curl --data "user=sharif&data=HelloWorld" http://site.com
```

See also [curl usage explained](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html)